# How to make same ng-model to accept different values inputs

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Let say I have an input textbox like this

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="Gender" type="text" placeholder="Gender Type"></ion-input>
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="hairCat" type="text" placeholder="Hair Type"></ion-input>
```

And also another textbox of the same type

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="Gender" type="text" placeholder="Gender Type"></ion-input>
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="hairCat" type="text" placeholder="Hair Type"></ion-input>
```

What I want is for the input to accept different values at once.

for example

```
[Boy Girl][black brown]
```

For more clarification, Let say I predefined a textbox like this

```
<ion-input type="text" readonly [(ngModel)]="values" value="adp"></ion-input>
 <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote" [(ngModel)]="vote"></ion-input>   

 <ion-input type="text" readonly   [(ngModel)]="values"  value="lp"></ion-input>
  <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote" [(ngModel)]="vote"></ion-input>
```

I have:

value   Vote
adp
lp

value is defined but vote will be imputted.

How can I make them accept different values?

Comment: Like you can type something different in 1 box vs the other?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking -- you mean that you have more than one `Gender` textbox at once and you want them to have different values? Or you want the gender and `hairCat` boxes to accept different values?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, yes, I want them to have the same ngModel but differet values. Like for example if you clone them.

Comment: You can't do that using the same ngModel since ngModel will bind to a property by its name -- i.e. it is the same property. Do you want a dynamic list of gender/hair forms, or is it a set number? (exactly two)

Comment: @TonyeBoro, so do you want to have one Gender textbox with Male value, while other Gender textbox will have Female value?

Comment: @whatthefish, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding two inputs to the same object so the values are the same.

Change `[(ngModel)]="hairCat" [(ngModel)]="Gender`" in the second text box to `[(ngModel)]="hairCat2" [(ngModel)]="Gender2"`.